# VBA Code to Insert Column and Paste Data - changing Date Value

Tags: vba, excel

I am running in to a road block and unable to figure this out.

I have a sheet, which has 9 columns, each with a header. 2 of those columns have a start date and end date. The 10th column, I subtract End Date by Start Date to get the number of days. These could be anywhere from 0 (only 1 day) to 5.

I am trying to do a VBA code, that would check the 10th column (Column J) and referencing to the number, insert a row right under it and also have the information that it contains.

I have the following code that inserts the information to Sheet2 with the added Rows and copies the data down in the new rows.

But the issue I am having is this:

J3 = 4, then insert 4 rows under J3 and copy data from A3:I3, except, for the Start Date and End Date, put the appropriate date.

Implying, say the Start Date is 1/1/2013 and End Date is 1/4/2013, then put

```
Sdate          Edate
1/1/2013    1/4/2013
1/2/2013    1/2/2013
1/3/2013    1/3/2013
1/4/2013    1/4/2013
```

Could this be possible? I know I could import this data to Access and do an Append Query, but my work does not like me to use Access.

This is the code that works with regards to inserting the rows and copying the data from all 10 columns to the new ones:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuildSortedSht()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim IP As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim scell As Variant


LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Set sht = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
Set IP = sht.Range("A2")

For Each scell In rng

If scell > 1 Then

  For i = 1 To scell

    Range(scell.Offset(0, -9), scell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
    IP.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:=False

    Set IP = IP.Offset(1, 0)

  Next i

Else

    Range(scell.Offset(0, -9), scell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
    IP.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
               SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:=False

    Set IP = IP.Offset(1, 0)

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you tidy up your question to give only the minimum required information and to be more specific about the inputs and outputs you intend to produce?

Comment: Also, a neater way of achieving the same as `LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row` would be `Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: And it's a good habit to get into using the declaration `Dim LastRow As Long` because the Integer type can't cope with all the rows in Excel and one day this will bite you : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1    'as you insert new rows that shift data, you have to go in a loop up: from bottom to top
        If .Cells(i, "J") > 0 Then
            .Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + .Cells(i, "J")).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

            'copy range(s) you want from row above
            .Range(.Cells(i + 1, "A"), .Cells(i + .Cells(i, "J"), "I")).Value = .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i, "I")).Value

            'create start:end dates in columns A:B (A = start date)
            MyDate = .Cells(i, "A")
            For j = i + 1 To i + .Cells(i, "J")
                MyDate = DateAdd("d", 1, MyDate)
                .Range(.Cells(j, "A"), .Cells(j, "B")) = MyDate
            Next j
         End If
     Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your code should be like this:

```
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1    'as you insert new rows that shift data, you have to go in a loop up: from bottom to top
        If .Cells(i, "J") > 0 Then
            .Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + .Cells(i, "J")).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

            'copy range(s) you want from row above
            .Range(.Cells(i + 1, "A"), .Cells(i + .Cells(i, "J"), "I")).Value = .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i, "I")).Value

            'create start:end dates in columns A:B (A = start date)
            MyDate = .Cells(i, "A")
            For j = i + 1 To i + .Cells(i, "J")
                MyDate = DateAdd("d", 1, MyDate)
                .Range(.Cells(j, "A"), .Cells(j, "B")) = MyDate
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End With
```